# Python for-loop is not passing variable past the first iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to combine three .txt files together. The first file contains one line that should be at the top of the page, the second line should contain the invoice information for the first client, then following should be the detail in the invoice. Each has an ID ranging between 31625 and 31643. The program should look at the first file, import the first line, then import the first line from the second file, then return any detail that has the key of 31625  then move move to the second line of the second .txt file. and so forth. 
Both the second .txt file and the third .txt file have the key in it.

I wrote a python script that inserts the first line, 
then it inserts the first line from the second .txt file, then it finds anything from the 3 .txt file that has the 31625 key, but stops there. How do I get the it to iterate through each key?

```
import sys

initial = open(r"dir:text1.txt","a+")

export = open(r"dir:text2.txt","r+")

invoice = open(r"dir:text3.txt3","r+")

detail = open(r"dir:text4.txt","r+")


for line in export:
    initial.write(line)


def inv_insert(a):
    for line in invoice:
        if str(a) in line:
            initial.write(line)

def det_insert(a):
    for line in detail:
        if str(a) in line:
            initial.write(line)


def exp_insert():
    for line in export:
        initial.write(line)

exp_insert()
for i in range(31625,31644):
    inv_insert(i)
    det_insert(i)

initial.close()
export.close()
invoice.close()
detail.close()
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried debugging your own code? What research have you done? You might want to review how Python treats whitespace. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You exhaust your file iterator after the first time. Just re-opened the file or `.seek` to the beginning

Comment: Unless the file is large -- just slurp it into a list in one line of code, after which you can iterate over it to your hearts content.

Comment: I debugged the code in pycharm and noticed it skips the if statement on the second go round and continues. It seems as if it reads the file, but does not go any further. I cannot find any other cases where someone has used it for the same purpose. I reviewed the documentation on for loops to make sure that I had written it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome fcha256, your code is not formatted correctly for python. I haven't run this but you should start with correct formatting like this and then troubleshoot your code:

```
    import sys

    initial = open(r"dir:text1.txt","a+")
    export = open(r"dir:text2.txt","r+")
    invoice = open(r"dir:text3.txt3","r+")
    detail = open(r"dir:text4.txt","r+")


    def inv_insert(a):
      for line in invoice:
        if str(a) in line:
          initial.write(line)


    def det_insert(a):
      for line in detail:
        if str(a) in line:
          initial.write(line)


    def exp_insert():
      for line in export:
        initial.write(line)


    exp_insert()

    for i in range(31625,31644):
      inv_insert(i)
      det_insert(i)


    initial.close()
    export.close()
```